# pure css conditionally change background-color of body

Tags: html, css

Is it possible in *pure* css to change the `background-color` of the `body` element depending of the id (or class) of the first div inside the `body` ?

For instance :

```
<body> 
  // background-color is black
  <div id="abc"> ... </div>
</body>


<body> 
  // background-color is red
  <div id="cde"> ... </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Well, @cimmanon closed the question already, however as stated in Joe's answer you cannot do it with pure CSS, but you can fake it though like this https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/u6cvdhdz/

Comment: @Mi-Creativity Thanks for the js-fiddle !

Comment: You welcome, I'm glad it helped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there's no way of doing this purely in CSS. You'll need to your javascript/jquery for that, which will change your body background for it.

```
if ($('#abc')[0]) {
   $('body').css('background','black')
}
if ($('#cde')[0]) {
   $('body').css('background','red')
}
```

Comment: OP asked for a "pure CSS" way to do it.